# Form behaving differently on phone than in resized browser. How do I replicate this?

Tags: ios, forms, replication

I coded a simple form, tested it on my pc in different browsers and browser sizes and it worked fine. When I open the page in my phone's browser (iPhone 6, Safari) the form behaves differently.

How do I replicate this behaviour in my browser so I can debug and fix the issue? I don't know why for example the label 'verende zadelpen' is behaving this way, but I need to fix it.

[example of what's happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOTKU.png)

Is there a way to replicate exactly this, in my browser?
I don't know any other way to check what classes are causing this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using chrome (im not sure on windows keys) but for mac you can press cmd, alt, I and it will show you mobile versions. For safari you can use: cmd, alt R.

Comment: That's what I used to make the 'browser' screenshot. This does not replicate the behaviour from my phone sadly. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using fixed widths on the form?

Comment: percentages only. I am using float on the textbox, not on the label that breaks. I can include my html/css but I guess that was not part of the original question.

Comment: I dont think adding the code would be such an issue as it sounds like it could be code related rather than browser.